# Aligning a text relative to the html canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas, alignment

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="450" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3; background-color:#999999;">

Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>

<script>

<!--normal canvas code-->

var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

<!--code for the text line-->

ctx.font = "42px Arial";

<!--place the words in mid x position and in upper 1/6 of y position-->

var canvasxposition = (c.width/2)-(ctx.fillText.x/2)

var canvasyposition = c.height/6

ctx.fillText("Hello World",canvasxposition,canvasyposition);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I am using a canvas and it will be later used for an image.
I need to align the text in the middle of x position and in top y position (1/6 of total height should be the y position)

I used the above code and found out that the following line has a problem.

I need to know what is wrong with it. I want to see the middle(y axis) of the text, in the middle (y axis) of the canvas.

```
var canvasxposition = (c.width/2)-(ctx.fillText.x/2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can align text from its own horizontal centerpoint using `context.textAlign`

You can align text from its own vertical centerpoint using `context.textBaseline`:

```
// align text from horizontal and vertical centerpoint of text
ctx.textAlign="center";
ctx.textBaseline="middle";
```

Example code and a Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/nT37D/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>
<script>
$(function(){

    // get references to canvas and context
    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    // crosshairs
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(0,canvas.height/6);
    ctx.lineTo(canvas.width,canvas.height/6);
    ctx.moveTo(canvas.width/2,0);
    ctx.lineTo(canvas.width/2,canvas.height);
    ctx.stroke();

    // align text from horizontal and vertical centerpoint of text
    ctx.textAlign="center";
    ctx.textBaseline="middle";

    // sample text
    ctx.font="18px arial";
    ctx.fillText("Hello World",canvas.width/2,canvas.height/6);

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <h4>Align text from horizontal and vertical centerpoint of text</h4>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```